# Initizalizing a return list of tuples in numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to retrofit some existing code to try to improve performance with numba. So maybe this will just not be feasible. But I need to return a specific data structure (or at least something quite similar) to what the next part of the program demands.

That data structure is a list of tuples with mixed types. I was hoping that as long as I explicitly define the return structure with fixed lengths when necessary, then I could just manipulate it in-place in the jitted function and then return it when finished. But it seems to have casting errors, so I thought that I should define the input types, but I don't know how I can do that.

The function (stripped to its most important parts), looks like this:

```
def myfunc(things):

    candidates = [(
        nb.uint32.cast_python_value(0),  # (a)
        nb.float64.cast_python_value(0), # (b)
        nb.float64.cast_python_value(0), # (c)
        nb.float64.cast_python_value(0), # (d)
        nb.int64.cast_python_value(0),   # (e)
        np.full(16, 0, dtype=np.uint32)  # (f) (Only needs to be some kind of Python iterable)
    )] * len(things)

    i = 0
    for thing in things:

        # ...
        # Do some processing which calculates a through f
        # ...

        candidates[i] = (a, b, c, d, e, f)
        i += 1

    return candidates
```

I thought that I could force the data types using these numba data type classes but it still complains:

```
Unknown attribute 'cast_python_value' of type class(uint32)
File "wind_off/blobber/core.py", line 27:
def process_cell(row, col, cell_window_lower_dist, cell_window_upper_dist, min_area, id_raster, area_raster, lcoe_raster,
    <source elided>
    candidates = [(
        nb.uint32.cast_python_value(0),
        ^
During: typing of get attribute at /data/eifer.kit.edu/boates/lowerc_offshore/wind_off/blobber/core.py (27)
File "wind_off/blobber/core.py", line 27:
def process_cell(row, col, cell_window_lower_dist, cell_window_upper_dist, min_area, id_raster, area_raster, lcoe_raster,
    <source elided>
    candidates = [(
        nb.uint32.cast_python_value(0),
        ^
python-BaseException
```

Is what I am doing simply not possible or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up the computation with Numba or use the `nopython=True`/`njit` mode, then you need to use Numpy array and not lists.
You can do that in Numpy using composite user-defined types. However, AFAIK, user-defined types cannot be recursive and cannot contain variable-sized arrays. Assuming the size of the last element of each tuple is 16 (or bounded by 16), you can create your own type using:

```py
candidateType = np.dtype([
    ('a', np.uint32), 
    ('b', np.float64), 
    ('c', np.float64), 
    ('d', np.float64), 
    ('e', np.int64), 
    ('f', np.uint32, 16)
])

def myfunc(things):
    candidates = np.zeros(len(things), dtype=candidateType)

    for i,thing in enumerate(things):
        a, b, c, d, e, f = i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, np.arange(16)+i
        candidates[i] = (a, b, c, d, e, f)

    return candidates
```

With Numba, you need first to convert the Numpy type ahead of time so it can compile the code later with it. Moreover, only the direct assignment seems to be supported at the time of writing (tuple-based pattern matching is not yet supported). Here is how to do that:

```py
candidateType = np.dtype([
    ('a', np.uint32), 
    ('b', np.float64), 
    ('c', np.float64), 
    ('d', np.float64), 
    ('e', np.int64), 
    ('f', np.uint32, 16)
])

numbaCandidateType = nb.from_dtype(candidateType)
@nb.njit
def myfunc(things):
    candidates = np.zeros(len(things), dtype=nbCandidateType)

    for i,thing in enumerate(things):
        # Arbitrary values just to provide a working example
        a, b, c, d, e, f = i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, np.arange(16)+i

        candidates[i].a = a
        candidates[i].b = b
        candidates[i].c = c
        candidates[i].d = d
        candidates[i].e = e
        candidates[i].f[:] = f

    return candidates
```

For more information you can take a look to the following references:

- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html
- https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.50.0/reference/types.html#numba.from_dtype